# While saving one to one relationship child object, illegalargumentexception occurs

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domain classes as follows:

```
    Class Parent{
         static hasOne = [child: Child]
         static mapping= {
                id(name: 'number', generator: 'assigned')
         columns {
               number(column: 'ST_NO') 
            }
         }
     }


    Class Child{
         Parent parent 
         static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]
         static mapping = {
          id(column: 'ST_NO',generator:'foreign', params: [ property: 'parent'])
       columns {
        parent(column: 'ST_NO', insertable: false, updateable: false)
              }
       }
```

Updating the child table works fine. But when i try to save into the child Table it keeps throwing me the following error

```
     IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [Child.id (expected type = java.lang.Long)]; target = [Child : (unsaved)], property value = [1234] setter of Child.id
```

While dumping the parent Object. I get the following validation error:

```
      Field error in object 'Parent' on field 'child': rejected value [null].
```

Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've never seen that `columns(Closure)` method. Where did you learn about it? And why is the table column for the id and parent the same?

Comment: I saw the columns(Closure) used in various examples. About id and parent being same , its because the parent's primary key is also the primary key for the child table. @EmmanuelRosa